# Why is chloroethene said to be a conjugated system?

Tags: organic-chemistry, resonance

Why is chloroethene said to be a conjugated system?Is it because of p orbitals present in chlorine or something?

Comment: The conjugation is weak though because the Chlorine lone pair is in a 3p orbital but the pi bond is consists of two 2p orbitals

Answer (score 4):

Conjugation can be between pi-bond and another pi-bond, lone pair of electrons and a pi-bond(as in your case) and pi-bond and a vacant orbital(p or d).

Answer (score -2):

Chloroethene is said to be a conjugated system because the lone pair on the chlorine atom in in conjugation with the double bond between the 2 carbon atoms.

See [this](http://www.expertsmind.com/CMSImages/2061_properties%20of%20vinyl%20chloride1.png) image for the resonating structures.

Comment: Here also: is called resonance and resonance structure. It has nothing to do with resonating.

Answer (score -2):

Chloro ethane is a conjugated system because of the +M effect of chlorine with the double bond of ethene. Chlorine has a tendency to resonate with a double bond by donating its lone pair. What this means is that the lone pair of chlorine is in an unhybridised atomic p orbital in the same plane as the p orbital of the adjacent double bonded carbon atom, due to which, the lone pair "jumps" from the p orbital of chlorine to the adjacent carbon (forming a double bond) and displaces the original double bond to the next carbon.

[image]

resonates to

[image]

Comment: This kind of explanation simplifies the concept beyond the useful. The concept you are trying to explain is resonance, which has nothing to do with resonating. Equally bad is using jump for electrons, also when in quotation, because this simply isn't happening. There is no displacing. Resonance is a superposition of contributors.

Comment: I am sorry for the use of non technical terms, i am a little new to chemistry